# R's environment

Tags: r

I would like to ask something about R's environments:
In the next simple code I create the local variable "v1".
"f1" lays in the global environment, as we can see when we type "environment(f1)".
My question is how can we access "v1" **from within the R console**. "v1$f1" is not working. Is there an explanation for this?

```
rm(list = ls())
f1 <- function() {
    v1 <- 1
}
environment(f1)
```

Next, if I create the environment "e1"

```
e1 <- new.env()
```

and I put "f1" inside "e1"

```
environment(f1) <- e1
```

When I use "ls(e1)" I do not receive "f1". Does anybody know why?

```
ls(e1)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: hmm, I usually use `assign('f1',f1,envir=e1)` for this sort of thing, but `?environment` does suggest that `environment(f1)<-e1` should work - I'm unsure why it doesn't.

Comment: `environment(f1) <- e1` sets the enclosing environment for `f1`; that is, the location where it will search for objects not defined within its own scope. `f1` itself doesn't have to exist in that location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local variable `v1` *does not exists* until you call the function `f1`, and then the environment where it lives is typically destroyed when `f1` exits. But you can get hold of it if you modify `f1`:

```
rm(list = ls())
f1 <- function() {
    v1 <- 1
    environment() # return the local environment
}

f1()$v1
```

For your second question, you assigned `e1` to `f1`, not the other way around. So `f1` has the environment `e1` where it looks for things. If you specify a parent environment to `new.env`, that's where it will continue looking for stuff:

```
e1 <- new.env(parent=baseenv())
e1$foo <- 42
bar <- 43 # Global variable, not found through e1

f2 <- function() {
   foo # Finds in e1
   bar # Not found...
}

environment(f2) <- e1
f2() # Error: object 'bar' not found
ls(e1) # "foo"
e1$f2 <- f2
ls(e1) # "f2" "foo"
```

Comment: ...Thanks, but also look at the "Related" section to the right, there are plenty of Q & A about environments in [r].